# Как получить ссылку на страницу eel

Tags: python, aiogram, бот, eel, веб-интерфейс

Хочу создать tg бота с веб интерфейсом, думаю использовать библиотеку eel, хочу что бы страница открывалась по нажатию кнопки в боте, возможно ли сделать такое, если да то как, если нет то какую библиотеку лучше использовать

ЯП: python

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос вашу попытку решить проблему.